# Allow crawling of only the home page of a sub-directory using robots.txt

Tags: html, robots.txt

I have

- `www.example.com` with WordPress

and

- `www.example.com/sitetwo` with another WordPress

I would allow crawling for the entire `example.com` and only the home page of `example.com/sitetwo`.
What I have to write in my `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Allow: /sitetwo/$
Disallow: /sitetwo/
```

`$` means "exact match" in this context.